# What is the best way to validate multiple records in MS Access through a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I work for a study where we enter in record information from paper forms into an MS Access database. And as a process of validation, we enter records twice and then compare the records together to make sure they match up. The idea being if they match up then the records are valid. We want to look at records which don't match with their complement records and reconcile the conflict between records.

The records exist in two tables named 'Entry1' and 'Entry2', all feilds are identical between the tables. The ID we match these records on between the tables is 'G2ID'. Side note, it is often the case that the Entry1 table will be ahead of the Entry2 record in terms of the number of entries. Normally the manual entry for Entry2 table is a 40 recrod lag behind Entry1 table.

My question(s):
a) Is there a query which will compare the records between tables and return all G2IDs which don't have matching records in 'Entry1' and 'Entry2' tables?
b) Is there a way to return each specific field where there is a conflict in those tables?

The current process runs a left join on Entry1 table and tries to match every single field in the query (eg [Entry1].feild1 = [Entry2].feild1 ... = [Entry1].feild100 = [Entry2].feild100). So the query is super long and hard to read/edit (this was not my doing, I inherited this database from someone who left the study recently). This result returns all records from Entry1 which don't match, but there are also sometimes cases where Entry2 will be ahead of Entry1. I want to try and make this query more robust for the sake of the people who have to do the reconciliation.

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: My initial thought was the `LEFT JOIN ... NULL` approach. Why does it matter if query is *super long and hard to read/edit*? You only need to create it **once**. What else is there to edit? As for other results, simply flip the tables and all references for non-matches in *Entry2*.

Comment: You could do it all in one comparison.  WHERE {concatenate all fields from entry1} <> {concatenate all fields from entry2}